# How to automatically create model from database using PetaPoco library, step by step?

Tags: petapoco

So this question has been asked before, and the most popular answer says installing petePOCO using the package manager console would automatically create folders (model>generated, etc.). It doesn't And the explanation of how to then generate the model loses further clarity from there.

Can someone offer step-by-step bullet points on how to generate you model automatically for use with petaPOCO?

I tried the answer to the previous question adn it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/hippasus/PetaPoco.DBEntityGenerator?